# VB.NET The report has no tables with crystalreport

Tags: vb.net

Guys

The Report has no tables in vb.net
[This my error please help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb9fm.png)

Comment: It can be helpful if you would post your code here. and not just from an image.

Answer (score 0):

you have to write

```
objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
```

Instead of

```
objRpt.SetDataSource(ds)
```